Knex.js first('*') return type does not include undefined
I'm new to Knex.js.
I'm curious about why the return type of first('*') and first() function calls are different.
import knex from 'knex'

const client = knex({
    client: 'better-sqlite3',
    connection: {
        filename: ':memory:',
    },
    pool: { min: 1, max: 8 },
    useNullAsDefault: true,
})

interface User {
    id: number
    name: string
    password: string
    email: string
}

// Type Inference: User
const result = await client<User>('user').where({ name }).first('*')

// Type Inference: User | undefined
const result = await client<User>('user').where({ name }).first()

.first('*') returns undefined at runtime when the name provided in the .where({name}) do not exist on the table user.
So I believe that the return type of .first('*') should be inferred as User or undefined.
